# Can I downcast an owned Any value without boxing?

Tags: rust

Suppose I want a generic trait implementation which does something different if the generic type is one specific type in particular:

```rust
enum StringIsSpecial {
  Special(String),
  NotSpecial,
}

impl<T: Any + Display> From<T> for StringIsSpecial {
  fn from(value: T) -> Self {
    // should return Special(value) if T is String,
    // or NotSpecial otherwise
  }
}
```

I found one way to do this as follows:

```rust
impl<T: Any + Display> From<T> for StringIsSpecial {
  fn from(value: T) -> Self {
    use StringIsSpecial::*;

    let boxed: Box<dyn Any> = Box::new(value);
    match boxed.downcast::<String>() {
      Ok(boxed_string) => Special(*boxed_string),
      Err(_) => NotSpecial,
    }
  }
}
```

I was curious if there is a way to do this without boxing and allocation. Conceptually, it feels like if I own the value and it's the correct type, I shouldn't need to move it to the heap and back to use it.

This is similar to [the example in the `any` module docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html#examples), except that's about a reference instead of an owned value so they can use `downcast_ref`.

Comment: `T: Any` is nearly meaningless. You probably want to implement this for some form of `dyn Any` (and also plain `String`).

Comment: @drewtato The example in the [`any` module docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html#examples) has a `T: Any`. What's the difference here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a mutable reference and use [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html):

```rust
enum StringIsSpecial {
  Special(String),
  NotSpecial,
}

impl<T: Any + Display> From<T> for StringIsSpecial {
    fn from(mut value: T) -> Self {
        let val_any = &mut value as &mut dyn Any;
        match val_any.downcast_mut::<String>() {
            Some(as_string) => {
                Self::Special(std::mem::take(as_string))
            }
            None => {
                Self::NotSpecial
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `String::default()` doesn't allocate, so this doesn't allocate either.

Answer (score 3):

With [`min_specialization`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) you don't have to use `Any` or boxes, unfortunately for now it requires nightly:

```rust
#![feature(min_specialization)]
use std::fmt::Display;

enum StringIsSpecial {
    Special(String),
    NotSpecial,
}

impl<T: Display> From<T> for StringIsSpecial {
    default fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        StringIsSpecial::NotSpecial
    }
}

impl From<String> for StringIsSpecial {
    fn from(value: String) -> Self {
        StringIsSpecial::Special(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `min_specialization` instead. It doesn't have soundness holes.

Comment: Right I always forget about it because the compiler tells you to use `specialization`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, using unsafe code and [`TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/struct.TypeId.html):

```rust
impl<T: Any + Display> From<T> for StringIsSpecial {
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<String>() {
            // First, wrap it in `ManuallyDrop` so we don't have double-drop.
            let value = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(value);
            // SAFETY: We checked this is `String`.
            let value = unsafe { std::mem::transmute_copy::<T, String>(&value) };
            return StringIsSpecial::Special(value);
        }
        StringIsSpecial::NotSpecial
    }
}
```

But prefer the `take()` approach of @virchau13.

Comment: I would definitely prefer with the `take` version, but this answer is great too for the case where we can't cheaply produce a value of the type we're casting to.